# CakePHP - Special query in Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'd like to paginate using a Circular query on MySQL, namely this:

```
SELECT *,
  (
      6371 * acos(
              cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )
            * cos( radians( lng )
            - radians($lng)
      )
    + sin( radians($lat)
   ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM {$this->table} HAVING distance < $dist
  ORDER BY distance LIMIT $offset , $limit;
```

Unfortunately, I see the [Pagination component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) only works through some query builder.

Is there a way I can use this query in a pagination anyway?

Comment: You should check out the section about virtual fields: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html - also, you might be interested in [geocoding-with-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/).

Comment: @mark I can't use virtual fiels here because the field has 2 parameters, `$lat` and `$lng`. But the geociding plugin I will look at later.

Comment: Aint an excuse :) There in the linked example it also takes two parameters - take a look at the code.

Comment: @mark I just found it. The docs don't mention you can add virtual fields after class declaration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out you can add virtual fields after the class declaration, like so:

```
public function addDistanceVirtualField($lng, $lat) {
    $this->virtualFields['distance'] = <<<EOT
    (
      6371 * acos(
              cos( radians( $lat) ) * cos( radians( {$Model->alias}.lat ) )
            * cos( radians( {$Model->alias}.lng )
            - radians($lng)
      )
    + sin( radians($lat)
   ) * sin( radians( {$Model->alias}.lat ) ) ) )
EOT;
}
```

Comment: I'd still use a behavior for a cleaner approach. But yep, that is basically the way to go.